# Compile and use a custom version of libstdc++ as a regular user

Tags: c++11, gcc, stl, linker, libstdc++

**I have to compile and run a modern program on a cluster with an outdated OS.** The program  employs some c++11 features and STL templates. The cluster's compiler toolchain (g++ v 4.4.7) supports almost all of c++11 features, but some important STL templates/classes are missing.

To make it work I'll have to either:

1. modify the program's source code, or
2. compile a **newer version of STL library** on a cluster and link against it **instead** of system-wide STL libs.

The 1'st route seems sub-optimal, because the program is currently in an active development by our lab, and it means we'll need to patch it by hand daily, or make a separate branch and regularly merge from trunk, or drop the support for c++11 features altogether.

So, is it possible to build a **libstdc++** version that is newer than the one installed system-wide, and link against it? And *if* it is possible, *how* could it be done?

Comment: 4.4.7? That's a six-year-old branch. Just build the whole GCC. Later versions of libstdc++ may well rely on features in newer versions of the compilers anyway.

Comment: This is a good idea, but is it possible to do under THAT g++ version at all? And how would I feed new libs to the linker? And what chance is there would be compatibility problems with, say, system-wide MPI libs and utils?

Comment: You might be better off with Docker or a similar container solution... I expect that after a while, more compatibility problems than just libstdc++ will arise; bypassing the cluster OS and running your app in a container would fix all these.

Comment: After some trial and error I was able to find the most recent GCC version that could be compiled in this environment. Luckily that version was just able to compile my (c++11 compliant) code with some very minor tweaks.